# How to add microphone to the keyboard for speech recognition?

Tags: voice-recognition, microphone

I am using Android 7.0 on a Samsung Galaxy S7 edge.

How to add microphone to the keyboard to "write" SMS or Facebook messages using speech recognition?

Comment: samsung keyboard apparently . how can i change it?

Comment: see instructions [here](http://webcazine.com/18906/galaxy-s7s7-edge-fix-missing-mic-button-in-keyboard/) for native keyboard .

Answer (score 0):

dunno if it is possible natively using the samsung keyboard, but thanks to @beeshyams i have installed , using the playstore, gboard.
Gboard contains the microphone per default